# "lighning:recordEditForm" Not able to create a record if master-detail relationship field is present

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am facing a strange issue.
I am trying to create a record using lightning:recordEditForm but not able to create a record.
I have a master detail relationship field "Account" on object "Book". When I have changed the relation to lookup it is working. But for master detail relationship it is not working. Please help me.

Below is the code

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
     <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>

    <lightning:recordEditForm  objectApiName="Book__c">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c"/>

        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>

</aura:component>
```

This is the error I am getting
[image]

Comment: As we can't update the MD field. So that might be issue.

Comment: I am trying to create the record. But the error is showing like that.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a combination of a bad error message (you are creating not updating) and a limitation of the recordEditForm component. 
The Component does not appear to handle the condition when you are creating the Detail record in a Master/Detail relationship. 
One workaround is if you are able to set the Master/Detail field to "reparentable", then the component seems to work.

Comment: Had a similar issue [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225288/lightningrecordform-values-not-detected-for-master-detail-lookup/225289#225289) with `lightning:recordForm`, and your reparentable option did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. The problem you are entering the data through developer console preview option. Add this component to lightning app or page using lightning app builder then its perfectly works.